# Cognos Transformer built cubes - Are they packages like Framework Manager built packages?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

To create new report we use framework manager to create the package to use with the Cognos Report studio?. Can we use the Cognos Transformer to built cubes in the reports?. Are those Cognos Transformer built cubes a PACKAGE?. Can we use this straightforward in the Report Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use MDCs in Report Studio.

They are consumed in packages.

This can be done in one of two ways.

- First, when you create the data source connection which points to the MDC, one of the last pages of the wizard asks you if you want to create a package.  Click on that checkbox and a package will be created automatically with the MDC in it.
- Second, you can use FM to import the data source into a model and add it to a package which you publish from FM.

Comment: Hi C'est, in your answers's last sentence do you mean to import the MDC into the FM?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The data source connection points to the MDC.  That brings in a reference to the data source into the model.   When you publish the package that reference gets put into the package (unless you've excluded it from the package definition) and, when report studio opens the package a query is made to get the metadata of the mdc and display it.

It's better to create the package when you're defining the data source connection as that's slightly less of a hassle and less rigmarole.

Comment: Hi C'est, Once we create a data cube and changed to package, do they NOT completely cutoff from the database tables?. ie if any change in the underlying table data will reflect immediately in the package and report?. Packages do they dynamically reflect the underlying table data in the Cognos reports?